# creating a Simon game in JS but something is going wrong need assistance

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var buttonColor = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];

var userClickedPattern = [];

var gamePattern = [];



var totalKey = [];


var level = 0;

$("*").on("keydown", function(m)  {
  var key = m.key;

  totalKey.push(key);
  var keyLength = totalKey.length;
  if (keyLength == 1) {
    nextSequence();
  }
});

function nextSequence() {
    userClickedPattern = [];
  $("#level-title").html("Level " + level );
  var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  var randomChosenColor = buttonColor[num1];
  gamePattern.push(randomChosenColor);
  flashandsound(randomChosenColor);
  level++

}

function flashandsound(n) {
  $("#" + n ).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);

  var audio = new Audio("sounds/" + n + ".mp3");
  audio.play();
}



$("div").on ("click", function() {
  const userChosenColour = $(this).attr("id");
 //to animate the userChosenColour
  $("#" + userChosenColour).addClass("pressed");

  setTimeout(function () {
      $("#" + userChosenColour).removeClass("pressed");
  }, 500);

  userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColour);

  flashandsound(userChosenColour);


  checkAnser(userClickedPattern.length -3);
})

function checkAnser(currentLevel){

if (gamePattern[currentLevel] === userClickedPattern[currentLevel]) {
  if ((userClickedPattern.length-2) === gamePattern.length) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      nextSequence();
    }, 1000);
  }


} else {
   $("#level-title").html('Game over, Press any key to start again');
   var audio = new Audio("sounds/wrong.mp3");
   audio.play();
   $("body").addClass("game-over");
   setTimeout(function () {
     $("body").removeClass("game-over");
   }, 1000);

   restart();
}

}

function restart() {
  totalKey = [];
  level = 0;
  gamePattern = [];
  userClickedPattern = [];
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #011F3F;
}

#level-title {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin:  5%;
  color: #FEF2BF;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;

}

.btn {
  margin: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 20%;
}

.game-over {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pressed {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px white;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simon</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
<h1 id="level-title">Press A Key to Start</h1>
  
<div class="container">
    
<div lass="row">

      <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green">

      </div>

      <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow">

      </div>
      <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue">

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="game.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

(For some reason the userClickedPattern is giving out value three times, example: If I clicked on yellow, it will  give yellow 3 times and not only that but since the gamePattern only provides one value, I am not able to frame a proper if statement)

(I am not able to frame a proper if statement so that the game work smooth, if someone can also explain what I am doing wrong that would be awesome. Thank you)

Comment: Instead of adding a `keydown` event handler to every element in the DOM (`$("*").on("keydown", function(m) { ... }`) use event delegation and add one on the `body`

Answer (score 0):

Your button divs are nested 3 deep.

```
<div class="container">
<div lass="row"> <!-- this should probably say class="row" -->
      <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green">
...
```

And your jquery selector adds an onclick to every div.

```
$("div").on ("click", function() {
```

This is why you're getting three values for every button press.
Try changing your selector from `$("div")` to `$("div.btn")`.

Comment: For more on why this occurs, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_bubbling